# how can I insert a number in a text field instead of a string?

Tags: swift, swiftui

how can I insert a Int number in a text field instead of a string?
In the textfield not if I enter a binding number it gives me an error because I should insert a binding string

Comment: Enter a string that _represents_ a number.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this textfield with keyboard type number.
        textField.keyboardType = .numberPad

Answer (score 0):

You can allow the keyboard to insert numbers only by using the following command

```
let myTextField = textField()
myTextField.keyboardType = .numberPad
```

then when keyboard appears only insert numbers.